# Non-real time Multiplayer Cocos2d iOS

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, multiplayer

How do you go about making a non-real time multiplayer (something like QuizUp). It's not turn based but rather matches up two single player rounds to see who wins right? Can anyone point me to a direction to look at?? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can use this nice SDK provided by AppWrap for creating Multiplayer Game Development   in Cocos2D. It's really simple to integrate and easy to use

http://appwarp.shephertz.com/game-development-center/cocos2d-game-developers-home/